Iconise, Save expression in notebook, or DumpSave?
After computing  an expression of size 4.8 Mb, Mathematica offers the options to Iconise or Save expression in notebook,  and there is also the possibilty to DumpSave.  What are the adantages of each of these  options?  Which is best?

DumpSave is a separate file. Save in notebook makes your notebook heavier and possibly more sluggish but self contained.
